# Git push throwing error: GH001: Large files detected

Tags: xcode, git, github, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am pushing my Xcode project which written in Swift to GitHub. In this project I used GoogleMaps SDK for IOS and GoogleMaps framework integrated with few other frameworks which made this project heavy as I expected. particularly there is one file called **GoogleMaps** is over 100MB which is violating GitHub's policy thus I am getting below error.

> C:\Users\Shyam Bhimani\Desktop\FindMyBuddy>git push
>
> Git LFS: (0 of 0 files, 1 skipped) 0 B / 0 B, 34 B skippedCounting
>   objects: 691, done.
>
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (597/597), done.
>
> Writing objects: 100%
>   (691/691), 60.52 MiB | 384.00 KiB/s, done.
>
> Total 691 (delta 161),reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git
>   Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
>   remote: error: Trace: a2d7f29c8861bcb6bd13498cfcd44ac3
>
> remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
>
> remote: error: File
>   Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/GoogleMaps
>   is 123.08 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB To
>   https://github.com/shyambhimani/FindMyBuddy.git  ! [remote rejected]
>   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/shyambhimani/FindMyBuddy.git'

So far I have tried

`Git lfs track 'Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/GoogleMaps'`

```
git lfs track '*.*' 

git lfs track '*.File'
```

However no luck It still gives me same error every time I push.

I do not know extention of that file so I tried `*.*` just in case if it works but it did not.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me to solve this issue. TIA

Comment: Are you paying for Git LFS?

Comment: No I am not paying. Is it only paid service ? Is there any way I can upload a project which is over 100MB? @CharlieFish

Comment: Just edited my answer. Forgot to mention the fact that since you are using CocoaPods and Google Maps it would be super easy to ignore that and re download when needed.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has a limit of 100MB unless you pay for Git LFS. Sadly there is no way to get around this unless you ignore files using `.gitignore`. But those files will no longer be tracked by git.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention for your specific case especially with a common framework such as Google Maps it is very easy to re download that at a later date using CocoaPods. Personally I would ignore that whole folder in `.gitignore` because after you pull down your repo you can always re download it easily.

Comment: Could you split the files for git, and recreate the original file from these after checkout?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen You are getting into a LOT of work at that point. Having to split each file and recreate it after checkout is getting FAR too complex. For every commit push and pull having to do that would really start to add up and be time consuming. Personally I wouldn't suggest it. GitHub also has a limit of 1GB for your entire repo. Not a hard limit but defiantly don't like repos over 1GB.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I would just suggest using Git LFS or not tracking the file in Git. I guess you COULD split the files and recreate them but I wouldn't recommend it especially in practice. Better solutions exist.

Comment: Why is this too complex? It is just a single line shell script for both splitting and recombining.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It could definitely be worse. But adding that one step of complexity is not something I would personally want to do. Especially when better solutions exist. Why split the file and recombine it when you could pay for Git LFS? OR just git ignore the file and since it's so easy to re download just re download it every time? I mean I guess you could split the file up. Just wouldn't be the path I would take personally. Especially for this particular situation since it's so easy to re download it.

Comment: Why?  Because the question was how to solve getting the file on github.  Just because I make a suggestion you did not, does not necessarily make it better or worse than yours.  It is up to OP to decide which approach will work the best.  There are usually other requirements like "files in git must be complete and not require internet resources which may go away" or "we do not want to give github money".  These may decide which is the best approach.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Agreed. Your solution is definitely valid and in the end it depends on the specific situation.